# how to push object ids to another schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like this:

```
var MusicSchema = new Schema({
    music_genres:[{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'music_genres',
    }],
    music: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
});
```

now, in front-end, i have a multi select where user chooses one or many different music_genres.

> so when clicked submit, sometimes I get (if user chose only one genre)
>   - 5cab466ed076761558a76148 or if multiple - [ '5cab466ed076761558a76148', '5cab4915d076761558a7614a' ].

So, if user chose only 1 genre, it's string but if user chose multiple, it's array.

```
router.post('/',async (req,res)=>{
    const newMusic = new Music();
    if(typeof req.body.music_genres === "string") req.body.music_genres = [req.body.music_genres];

    for(var i in req.body.music_genres) newMusic.music_genres.push(req.body.music_genres[i]);  
    await newMusic.save();
```

Question: I hate when I wrote if statement and checking if it's string, make it array. I also hate for statement. Is there any way to make this code better without if and for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ternary with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of a loop with`push()`

```
 router.post('/',async (req,res)=>{
    const newMusic = new Music();
    typeof req.body.music_genres === "string" ? newMusic.music_genres = 
      [req.body.music_genres]: newMusic.music_genres = [...req.body.music_genres];
    await newMusic.save();
```

**Example**

```js
let foo = 'foo';
let arr = ['a', 'b'];
let bar = [];
a = foo;
typeof a == 'string' ? bar = [a] : bar = [...a];
console.log(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove for loop from the code you should use mongoose `insertMany` function as you can see in its official document here [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany), you can pass an array to this function then it will handle the bulk creation.

but for your first issue I think the best approach is make the request body integrated from client side so you can easily make the string an array with one element in it, I think it will be better for the consistency of server side code.

Comment: can you provide the code how you'd do it? because i am not saving insertMany in my music model, but in my music.music_genres sub document